# how to get month name from month number in odoo 8

Tags: python-2.7

```
def generate_leave(self, cr, uid,ids, fields, context=None):
        if context is None:
            context = {}
        month_split = self.browse( cr, uid,ids)
        print "\n\n\n\n\n\n DATEE",month_split.name 
        dt =  datetime.strptime(month_split.name, "%Y-%m-%d")   
        year = dt.year
        print "\n\n\n\n YER",year
        month = dt.month
        print "\n\n\n MNTH",month
        currentMonth = datetime.now().month
        print "\n\n\n\n\n CURR MNTH",currentMonth
        date = dt.day
        print "\n\n\n\n\n\n DATTE",date
        day = dt.day
        print "\n\n\n\n\n\n DAYY",day
```

I have tried for this but i cannot able to achieve it.i have used like "%b" and "%B" but nothing works.

Comment: You can use `dt.strftime('%B')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the documentation at http://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html

```
import calendar

month_name= calendar.month_name[3]

print month_name
```

This works perfectly for me. This returns "March"

***In your case you should use like this***

```
month_name= calendar.month_name[dt.month]
```

Comment: Did you try like this calendar.month_name[3] ?